# XPath on namespace-unaware documents

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm running an XPath on a document that was parsed with namespace unaware set.

The path to the element I'm trying to get is `/path/to/the/element` and that works. This also works: `/path//element`.

However once I remove the root itself: `//element` the resultset is empty.

I've currently running the xpath on the Document instance itself, I've tried running it on `Document.getDocumentElement()` (just to be sure) and that yields the same results.

If I set the document to `namespace aware` this does work: `//tns:element`.

Any reason why such a relative path wouldn't work on namespace unaware documents?

Comment: Did you try //*/element ?

Comment: If `/path/to/the/element` works, I'm inclined to say it is impossible that `//element` does not yield any results. We need to be able to _reproduce_ your issue, though. Please show [minimal, complete and verifiable samples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the Java code, the input document and of the output you get (vs. the output you expected).

Comment: @Paolof76 `//*/element` is a subset of `//element`, so it is impossible that `//*/element` returns more results than `//element`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: According to the XPath standard, yes; but we're already seeing "impossible" behavior (`/path//element` returns more than `//element`), so something else is going on.

Comment: @LarsH Impossible behaviour is unlikely with standard XPath libraries (as you know very well, I know), so as long as we do not see the code to reproduce those impossibilities, I might as well believe that improper use of XPath expressions is the cause of error.

Comment: @Mathias: I agree. And improper use could include almost anything. My point is that Paolo's question could conceivably reveal something significant; we just don't know.

Comment: @LarsH You are right of course, I should not be so presumptuous. Thanks for reminding me.  It's definitely an interesting case, I'd love to see the code.